# How does one line typescript syntax works

Tags: typescript

(I am fairly new to node,es6 and typescript. This is the first application actually I am working on)  I have the following code that I am trying to reference for connecting to dynamodb in typescript but I am not able to the generic part of the syntax:

i have tried looking into typescript and es6 syntax but didn't anything helpful.

```
  public readonly getItem = async (
tableName: string,
key: AttributeMap
): Promise<AttributeMap | null> =>
  this.dynamodbGet({
    TableName: tableName,
      Key: key
   }).then(({ Item }) => (Item !== undefined ? Item : null));
```

I am not able to understand the syntax of this part of the code

```
 : Promise<AttributeMap | null> =>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the chapters on Union Types and from Nullable types from [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

The basic idea is that under `strictNullChecks` types can't hold the value `null` by default, you need to explicitly say something might be `null`. So `Promise<AttributeMap | null>` means the promise might return  `AttributeMap` or `null` and you need to check the result to determine which one it is (also see type guards also [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html))

Answer (score 2):

This is a part of a class. It defines arrow method on class instance. It uses class field that TypeScript implements differently to [this proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). The rest of syntactic differences with JavaScript are types. `Promise<AttributeMap | null>` signifies that a function returns a promise of `AttributeMap | null` type; all `async` functions return promises by design.

ES6 counterpart that TypeScript will compile to will look like:

```
constructor() {
 this.getItem = (tableName, key) => {
   return this.dynamodbGet({ TableName: tableName, Key: key })
   .then(({ Item }) => (Item !== undefined ? Item : null));
 };
}
```

The use of `async` is unjustified here because the function uses raw promises and doesn't benefit from `await` syntax.